# Проверка на пунктуацию

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Проверьте пожалуйста на пунктуационные ошибки.

> Из юга России поздравляю с праздником.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конце поздравления обычно ставится восклицательный знак.

По огромному желанию автора,  в предложении может быть и тире (дело вкуса и желания, не ошибка).

Ошибка - грамматическая: предлог *из* парный к предлогу *в,* в то время как *с* - *на*: из школы - в школу, с фабрики - на фабрику.

*С юга России - поздравляю с праздником!*